# Rspec: stub relationship find (chain)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Controller:

```
@organization.topics.find(params[:id])
```

How can I stub this in my controller_spec with Rspec?  (`@organization` IS being set in my spec helper)

I've tried:

```
controller.stub_chain(:topics, :find).with("37") { mock_topic }
Topic.stub(:find).with("37") { mock_topic }
```

Neither of the above seem to work.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the `@organization` variable (you indicate that you do) then you should be able to:

```
@organization.stub_chain(:topics, :find).and_return(mock_topic)
```

I don't believe (unless they've changed the API to stub_chain, but I don't see anything of that nature in the docs) you can specify a .with('37') when using stub_chain.  If it is absolutely necessary that you specify what variable is passed to the find method (and it rarely is), you'll have to take the long route:

```
# This line is attempting to fake-out the .topics association and
# just return a mock of *whatever*, since it's just an intermediary
# step to where we really want to get to.
topics = @organizations.stub!(:topics).and_return(mock_model(Topic))
topics.stub!(:find).with('37').and_return(mock_topic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just:

```
@organizations.topics.stub!(:find).and_return(mock_whatever)
```

Comment: That, combined with mock_model(Topic, :id => 37) should work.

Comment: If the intention is to stub the call to .topics also, then this will not work.

Comment: True, but you could then have a mock that expects the call to :find.